# How do I get Debian to use systemd-logind for user session control?

Tags: debian, session, logind

I have one Debian Sid system that uses logind for its user sessions. It is odd that that system is not even running systemd. The logind sessions are independent of X and are in effect for the tty sessions before X is even started. However, I do not know how this occurred and even the distro's lead developer cannot explain it.

However, my main system is another Debian Sid distro (Siduction Linux) that is running systemd 204-7. logind is running and active, but it is not managing the user sessions. My question is, how would I go about switching session control from console-kit to logind?

Comment: See this [Arch Wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/General_Troubleshooting#Session_permissions) and remove any CK stuff from your startup files...

Comment: I have looked at that several times. It doesn't tell me what to do to get it to work, just how to see if it is working. And ck doesn't start until X starts; if loginctl is working, it should already be active before X starts.

Comment: It does tell you how to get it to work: you just need to follow the links. It also assumes that `systemd-logind.service` is running.

Comment: Ok, thank you jasonwryan. I guess I am too dumb to understand it. And, as I said, the systemd-logind service IS running: "systemd-logind.service      loaded active running   Login Service"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I discovered a solution. I'm not sure how correct it is, but it is working, although with a few glitches.

The main solution was to add line

```
-session optional pam_systemd.so
```

to file `/etc/pam.d/login` and

```
session optional pam_systemd.so
```

to file `/etc/pam.d/common-session`. This requires package `libpam-systemd`.

This worked for sessions in a tty console, but still had no effect on gui sessions. In order to have it effective for gui sessions, I worked around that by bypassing slim, logging in at the console, and running startx.